# Character type casting to Integer type

Tags: java, char, int

I've been learning Java for 2 weeks. 
I would like to know how casting actually works when a method parameter is given and its type is integer and within the method it is compared with a char type.

If I change '1' to 1 and '7' to 7, it doesn't make the comparison at all.
However, if I change the parameter int to char, it makes the comparison.

```
boolean isValid(int ch) {
    if(ch < '1' | ch > '7' & ch != 'q') return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Comment: `1` is not the same as `'1'`. `ch < '1'` is the same as `ch < 49`, since 49 is the codepoint value of `'1'`.

Comment: @AndyTurner The really interesting question here: what would be a good DUP to close this question against?! The one suggested by aydinugur ... probably not.

Comment: Side note: it's better to use `||` and `&&` in conditions rather than `|` and `&`. Although logically equivalent, the `||` and `&&` versions short-circuit, meaning the comparison stops if the result is known by calculating only the left side. This is almost always what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andy Turner already mentioned: '1' is not the same as 1.

You will see it by using `Chararacter.getNumericValue()`. This will parse the given char into its numeric integer value.

Example:

```java
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue('1')); // This will print 49.
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you replace `'1'` with `1`, then also it makes the comparison.
The condition `if(ch < 1 | ch > 7 & ch != 'q')` does gets executed.

The difference now is, this time the decimal value of character `ch` is compared with decimal `1` and `7`. This is so, because when we assign a `char` type value to `int` type variable then the decimal value of that ASCII character gets assigned.

Ex: if you call the isValid() like `isValid('q')` , then then in the method `isValid(ch)` , ch gets the value `113`, which is decimal value of ASCII character `q`. So the condition is effectively
`if(113 < 1 | 113 > 7 & ch != 'q')` , which gives `true`